# Save data from 1 page and add that data to a tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hey guys i have 2 views the first has a UITableView. The Second Has a textField and when the user presses a "Save" button on the second page, i want the textFields text to be added to the tableView. Here is the code i'm using

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
CheckListPracticeViewController * obj = [[CheckListPracticeViewController alloc]init];
[obj.cells insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"%@ "[cells objectAtIndex:0]);
[obj.myTableView reloadData];}
```

For some reason the data isnt being added to the table View does anybody know whats wrong?? Also the NSLog doesnt Work in this method. Thanks a lot Guys :D

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are creating a new instance of `CheckListPracticeViewController` and updating it rather than the current one which has presented this view controller modally.

Change the first line to,

```
CheckListPracticeViewController * obj = (CheckListPracticeViewController *)self.parentViewController;
```

**EDIT**

First of all be consistent with your data model. If you are loading an array of dictionaries from the plist and later adding strings into that array then you have a serious problem. I will suggest that you create a dictionary object with name and other stuff and add that to the array. I would say doing `[obj.cells insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:textField.text forKey:@"name"] atIndex:0];` instead of `[obj.cells insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];` will fix this current error but I doubt that will fix your problem.

Comment: ok thanks for the help, but this code didnt work? So do you know of anything else i did wrong?? Thanks :D

Comment: What does your `NSLog` statement log? Provided it should be `NSLog(@"%@ ", [obj.cells objectAtIndex:0]);` and also remove the `reloadData` call at the end and add that to `CheckListPracticeViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` method.

Comment: alright i did what you suggested and i still have the same outcome, i get a "SIGABRT" message on this line of code:   cell.textLabel.text = [[cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];

Comment: i dont know if you know, but my tableView is populated by a plist and i stored the plist's info into the cells mutable array

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cell.textLabel.text = [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` as you are adding a string i.e. `textField.text` in your code above.

Comment: yeah but i have a checklist on this table and i use that to populate the table from the plist if i do it the way you posted, i get a crashed program.

Comment: @Legolas Thanks. @kurt moyer I have updated my answer to state my understanding of your problem.

Comment: mmkay i added the code posted above which stores the textfields text in a dictionary, now what should i do to fix the problem of the tableview not adding the data?

Comment: @Deepak : Any help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700184/sliding-uitabbaritems-in-uitabbarcontroller ?

Answer (score 0):

You are each time the button is pressed you alloc/init a new `obj`, try adding the new data into your actual container.

Comment: hmm ok i just tried it and nothing different happened :( any other suggestions?? Thanks

Comment: no, you **re**instanciate the container each time. Since it is a fresh new instance, you in fact don't add the data to the container which is your actual container for cells and table view.

Comment: ok if my actual container is a plist. so should i try to add it there?

Comment: no, add the data to the container in which the table view data source is picking values.

Comment: ok i think i know what you mean... and what do you mean my "picking values" ??

Comment: the table view data source is the object responsible for giving the cells and other informations to the table view.That's what I meant, but just to know where is this action method defined actually ?

Comment: umm im really sorry about all the questions, im really new to programming im only 16 and ive been doing it for about 1 year so if i aggrivate you with all the questions, im sorry, and which action method?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating another instance of `CheckListPracticeViewController`. I assume thats where your table is. If you are going back to `CheckListPracticeViewController` (I assume you do since you use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`) you will have to pass your view controller as a `week reference` or use `NSNotification` or use `NSUserDefaults` to store and retrieve this object in the `CheckListPracticeViewController`.

**EDIT**

Pass the `CheckListPracticeViewController` by weak reference to the view that has `UITextField`.

example:

in the .h of your `UITextField` class create a controller reference.

```
@property(nonatomi,assign)CheckListPracticeViewController *controller;
```

then when you create your new `UITextField` controller class pass the reference to its creator throught `controller` instance.

//in CheckListPracticeViewController.m file

```
myEdiotr.controller = self;
```

Later use controller instance to save the text from the `UITextField`.

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
  [controller.cells insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];
  [controller.myTableView reloadData];
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: ok so i should store the textfield's text in NSUSerDefaults, then retrieve it and store it in the array that is populating my table??

Comment: You could or you can pass the controller by week reference. That's the best solution for it. Example posted in an answer.

Comment: @kurt it has to work, maybe you did something wrong, paste the code where you create the view that has the UITextfield.

Comment: wait create the view? what do you mean? and im sorry im a noob :D haha

Comment: @paste the code where show up the UITextFiewld view containter, if you whether you do it with UIViewController or just plain UIView

Comment: ok i used:   -(void)viewDidLoad{
    string = textField.text;
    [super viewDidLoad];
} to store the text into a string and then i used:   - (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    [controller.cells insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];
    [controller.myTableView reloadData];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
 to try to save the text to my cells array!!

Comment: There is couple of problems here, on viewDidLoad there should not be anything in the textField, since the view has not yet been presented. Second I still don't know how you created this UIViewController in the code of your super ViewController. Third you can't call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES` to close itself.

Comment: ok so i erased the string = textField.text; code, and im not sure what you mean about how i created my UIViewController? and why cant i use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES; ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely one of these.

1. Check if array `cells` is allocated. **Most likely it is not**. That is why it is not being added to the tableView. You can add it to the `init` method so that you initialize the array before adding to the array.
2. Try `NSlogging` the contents of the array at various points. This will let you know if its exactly what's going on. NSLog the array in `IBAction` of Add-method, `viewWillAppear`
3. You need to make sure that your array is `allocated` before adding data to it.
4. NSLog the content of `textField.text` before adding it to the array. I am guessing that it is not a property, and it is simply null.
5. Make sure you had assigned `self.myTableView = tableView` at the end of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: umm im pretty sure the array is allocated, i wrote   cells [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile]; and my file is a NSString that is written like : NSString * myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:funds ofType:plist];

Comment: Okay. Where is it allocated ?

Comment: And is are you adding the modal view controller in that method ? and are you adding the modal view controller before or after allocating array ?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean my adding the mvc?

Comment: Hm. You should have used `presentModalViewController` : someViewController. Because you have posted `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` in your code above. I am asking about that.

Comment: oh yeah i used that in my firstViewController! i used this in my add: method which sends me to the second view!

Comment: Try NSLogging array contents in `IBACtion of add method`, `viewWillAppear` of firstviewcontroller and paste it.

Comment: ok so do you mean something like :    - (void)add
{
    MyDetailController * detail = [[MyDetailController alloc]init];
    detail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:detail animated:YES];
    [detail.textField becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", [cells objectAtIndex:0], [cells objectAtIndex:1]);
    [detail release];
    
}
i added the NSLog statement just now and this button just takes us to the second view controller

Comment: Yeah. What do you see in the NSLogs. Just do `NSLog (@"%@", cells);` in the places I had suggested.

Comment: i also added a NSLog in the save: method now it looks like this :    - (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    [controller.cells insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];
    [controller.myTableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} and the text is displayed in the console, so i dont know why its not being added to the table view ?

Comment: Okay what do you see in other NSlogs ? Just do NSLog (@"%@", cells); in the places I had suggested. Lets find out if it is allocated.

Comment: ok i did NSLog in the add: method, the save: method and they are both printing out exactly what i want them to! So i beleive that means the array is allocated!

Comment: It printing out the contents of the array ? What about in `viewWillAppear` ? Also write down `[self.tableView reloadData];` in viewWillAppear

Comment: yes it is! ok let me try that! and i have [self.myTableView reloadData]; in both the viewWillAppear and in viewDidLoad!

Comment: If it is a tableViewController, just do `[self.tableView reloadData]`. And make sure that you had set `[self.myTableView = tableview];`

Comment: i also have a NSLog in my saveData: method, and its not printing out when the method is called so what does that mean?

Comment: Post the NSLog in your question and explain it there

Comment: kk i did that! now what do you think i should do? do you have any more ideas?