# Add data to a table View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save data from 1 page and add that data to a tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698333/save-data-from-1-page-and-add-that-data-to-a-tableview)

Jey guys i have 2 views the first has a UITableView. The Second Has a textField and when the user presses a "Save" button on the second page, i want the textFields text to be added to the tableView. Here is the code i'm using

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
CheckListPracticeViewController * obj = [[CheckListPracticeViewController alloc]init];
[obj.cells insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];
self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"%@ "[cells objectAtIndex:0]);
[obj.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

The table view wont add the new text, does anyone know my problem?? Thanks a lot for the help in advance:D