# iPhone Modal View Animation Help

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I have not done much animation, and I need some help with this. I have a `tabBarController` as my root controller, and I want to have another `tabBarController`, and I want to bring it up as a Modal View Controller, and I have a problem with the animation.

There are currently four animations for `modalViewControllers`, namely

```
typedef enum {
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

I want a different animation - slide from the right to the left.  - **How can I do this animation?**

Any help with this?

---

**Edit:**

My idea to push a tabBarController onto the navigation stack sucks! Apple's comment on this approach:

> You never want to push a tab bar controller onto the navigation stack of a navigation controller. Doing so creates an unusual situation whereby the 
>   tab bar appears only while a specific view controller is at the top of  the navigation stack. Tab bars are designed to be persistent, and so this transient approach can be confusing to users.

I am out of ideas. Someone help me with the animation for modal view controllers.

Comment: There is always `UIModalTransitionStyle`, but unfortunately there is not an animation that matches navigation controller transition style. I think you should use your alternative idea and use navigation controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the animation code manually. Here are the general steps:

- Create a subclass of `UIViewController` (essentially a dud controller to house your `UITabBarController`) - I usually call this `ShellViewController`.
- In the `ShellViewController`'s `init` method (whichever one you would use), set its `frame` outside of the screen to the right, e.g. `[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];`
- Create two methods within `ShellViewController`

  - `- (void)presentSelf`
  - `- (void)dismissSelf`
- Create an instance of `ShellViewController` when you want to present your `UITabBarController`
- Place your `UITabBarController` instance inside of the `ShellViewController` instance
- Call `[currentView addSubview:shellViewController.view];`
- Use the custom methods above to present and dismiss the `ShellViewController` housing your `UITabBarController`
- Deal with memory management as your business logic dictates

Here is the code for animating-in (e.g. the `- (void)presentSelf` method):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.15]; //the double represents seconds
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[[self view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Here is the code for animating-out (e.g. the `- (void)dismissSelf` method):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.15];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[[self view] setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Keep in mind that these animation methods do *only* that: animate. They don't disable interaction with the current view nor with the `ShellViewController`'s view/subviews which are being animated in/out. You'll need to manually disable user interaction during animation and then reinstate it after the animation is finished. There is a `UIView` method that performs a selector when animation is finished:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(enableUserInteraction)];
```

You can put this right after the `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]` in each animation block above. Of course, you would need to write the `enableUserInteraction` method yourself... and `disableUserInteraction` method for that matter.

It is a hassle to go this route, but it works. Once you get the `ShellViewController` written up, it makes for a nice reusable snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Embed your root tab bar controller in a UINavigationController. If it doesn’t let you, stick a UIViewController in between them (making: UINavigationController embeds UIViewController, which has a UITabBarController’s view added to it). It’s nasty-bad, but it ought (!) to work.

Answer (score 0):

Modal view controllers don't slide in because that's the standard stack animation (pushing or popping). That's confusing to users. If it's modal you really should slide it up from the bottom or do a flip or something.

Why do you need a tab bar on a modal view? Typically modal views are used for things like data entry, audio playback, etc. The [tab bar HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52) states "in general, use a tab bar to organize information at the application level". Having a tab bar in a modal view controller breaks that. Granted one doesn't have to follow every guideline in the HIG exactly but this is a case where you really should consider following Apple's advice.

Can you tell us more about your specific use case so we can make suggestions on what might be an appropriate solution? Perhaps a segmented control is more appropriate?

Comment: I wanted to create sliding tab bars. But decided to bring up a modal view for the next set of tabBarItems. I require a sliding animation for that purpose- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700184/sliding-uitabbaritems-in-uitabbarcontroller