# Change the animation style of a modal UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uimodalpresentationstyle

I would like to change the default animation of the presentModalViewController (sliding from bottom to top) so that it is the same as the animation in the UINavigationController (sliding from right to left)....How is this possible?

I couldn't find a default animation setting when looking at the docs for uimodalpresentationstyle

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780916/iphone-modal-view-animation-help

Answer (score -1):

look at UIModalTransitionStyle